# android - Infinite in other thread cause high cpu loading. why?

Tags: android

[high cpu loading screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dRBt.jpg)
Please see the screenshot hyperlink. Does anyone knows what's going on?

I want to do keep detecting and send message through socket in while loop. But it cause my app high cpu loading and getting slower and slower, then stop finally. So, I simply the code like screenshot. The problem is still there. If I can't write the code like screenshot and of course I can reach what I want. Does anyone have any idea?

I monitor by android studio and get 97% runs in "android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce".

Thank you for your help~

Comment: I create a thread by a runnable I implement. The only thing in this runnable is "while(true) {}". Then it cause slower and slower and stop. I think I might lost some concept in Android programming. Could anyone give some advices? Thank you so much!

Comment: `while(true)` and what is in the loop body?

Comment: I change my code to be empty in the while loop. The problem is still there. Getting slower and slower.

Comment: BTW, the loop is not running on UI thread.

Comment: so you are doing nothing in the `while (true)` loop? it makes no sense... (even if it is in the background thread) what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Originally, i create a thread run infinite loop to send a message by socket. Most of time it just checks if socket is null or not but cause app slower and slower. Then I changed the code just do nothing in the loop. But the problem is still there. So, I want to know is there anything i missed in android programming? is it a wrong way? Thank you!

Comment: I add a screenshot and more information. Please take a look if you have free time. Thank you!

Comment: I add `Thread.sleep()` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

"The thread has a while loop to deal with tasks about socket"

ANRs indicates you are doing an excessive amount of work on the primary thread. Without showing your code we cannot be sure what causes it, but since you mentioned a while loop I guess you are either not running on a new thread or blocking the UI thread in some other place.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I create a thread by a runnable I implement. The only thing in this runnable is "while(true) {}". Then it cause slower and slower and stop. I think I might lost some concept in Android programming. Could you give some advices? Thank you so much!

Comment: I add a screenshot and some information. Please take a look if you have free time. Thank you so much!

Comment: The thread will continue running whilst the application lives, so if you close and open the app it will probably start another thread while the other one is still running. In addition the given thread will consume all the CPU time it can get because it never stops checking if it can stop. (This can be alleviated with `Thread.sleep()` as you commented). You need to read up on the android lifecycle and figure out a way to do the data processing without an infinite loop.